# What kind of object is the set of all maps of the plane that commute with a fixed area-preserving map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am playing a bit with area-preserving maps and I arrived to the following question. I am wondering if anyone knows something.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ be an entire function such that $\det f'=1$ everywhere. Moreover we assume that $f^{-1}\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ is also entire. An example of such map is the area-preserving Henon map.

Let $S_f=\{g:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2|f\circ g=g\circ f\}$. It there anything that can be said about $S_f$?

For example: 
Does it contain non-trivial elements?
Are all such $g$ entire?
Is it the case that $\det g' =1$?
Is it a group?
If yes, is it commutative?

I am not sure about the tags. Feel free to modify them.

Following Alex's comment: if we assume that $g$ is locally invertible, does this imply that $g$ is invertible?

Comment: Here's a very easy observation: If $f$ has a fixed point $a$, then the constant function $g(x) = a$ commutes with $f$. This shows that if $f$ has a fixed point, then $S_f$ is not a group, since $g$ is not invertible (and it also gives an example with det $g'$ = 0$). However, $S_f$ is always a monoid, since it obviously contains the identity map and is closed under composition.

Comment: Ah, that is very true. More conditions are needed. I am tempted to assume invertibility, but maybe it will be too much.

Comment: If you take $f$ to be the identity function, then $S_f$ is just the set of *all* functions $\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^2$, which includes some pretty nasty ones. To make the question more interesting, you probably need to  increase the hypotheses on $f$ as well on the $g\in S_f$.